# How to perform following query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to perform following query and is failing.How can fix it?

```
decalre curPar int;
begin
select degree int curPar from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild online parallel 3;
alter index "SAPR3"."Z" parallel curPar;
select degree from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
end;
--- Solution is not working

var curPar number;
exec select degree into :max_degree  from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild online parallel 3;
alter index "SAPR3"."Z" parallel curPar;
select degree from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
```

/

Comment: typo: `decalre` should be `declare`. What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: For DDL statements you should use dynamic sql. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Apart from this please provide exact details of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare instead of decalre

SELECT ... INTO instead of SELECT ... INT

Datatype int - not exists in Oracle

You can use DDL operations (alter index) only with dynamic SQL (execute immediate)

```
declare
 curPar NUMBER;
begin
 select degree into curPar from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
 execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild online parallel 3';
 execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" parallel '||curPar;
 select degree into curPar from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

alter index is not a PLSQL command. Use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

```
declare curPar integer;
begin
  select degree into curPar from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
  execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild online parallel 3';
  execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" parallel curPar';
  select degree into curPar from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not execute a [DDL](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/what_are_the_difference_between_ddl_dml_and_dcl_commands) query from within a pl/sql block. If you need to do so, you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

```
    SQL> begin
  2     alter index i1 rebuild parallel 1;
  3 end;
  4 /
    alter index i1 rebuild parallel 1;
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

With `execute immediate`:

```
    SQL> declare
  2      vSQL   varchar2(100);
  3      curPar integer;
  4  begin
  5      select 1 into curPar from dual;
  6      vSQL := 'alter index i1 rebuild parallel ' || curPar;
  7      execute immediate vSQL;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I get following error:  
SQL> execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild online parallel 3';
BEGIN immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild online parallel 3'; END;

                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild
online parallel 3" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild
online parallel 3" to continue.


SQL>

Comment: Here is error:
  1  declare
  2  curPar int;
  3  begin
  4  select degree into curPar from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
  5  execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" rebuild online parallel 3';
  6  execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" parallel curPar';
  7  select degree into curPar from dba_indexes where index_name='Z';
  8* end;
SQL> /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02243: invalid ALTER INDEX or ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW option
ORA-06512: at line 6


SQL>

Comment: Pay attention to curPar; you have to concat the variable `curPar`, not insert the string `'curPar'` in your statement; the statement would be like `execute immediate 'alter index "SAPR3"."Z" parallel ' || curPar;`  ( see my example)